# CSS: Center element vertically

Tags: css, flexbox

**Background**

Here is scenario - https://codepen.io/37816/pen/LYeNPEN

```
<form class="aui">
  <div class="field-group">
    <label for="comment-input">Comment</label>
    <textarea class="textarea" ></textarea>
    <a id="cssthis" href="#" fieldhelp="" data-helplink="local" style="">
      <span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-question-circle"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Request**

EDIT: Answers so far do not give solution to the question that was asked. Is there a way to adjust id="cssthis" **ONLY** using inline styling to be able to center vertically to div class="field-group"?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox. If you only want the question mark centered, you can use `align-self: center`

```css
/* this next block shows the alignment of the label to the textarea */
.textarea {
  padding: 10px;
}

.field-group {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  align-items: baseline;
  /* align-items: start; if you don't want to align the label to the text inside the textarea */
}

#cssthis {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<form class="aui">
  <div class="field-group">
    <label for="comment-input">Comment</label>
    <textarea class="textarea">Content</textarea>
    <a id="cssthis" href="#" fieldhelp="" data-helplink="local" style="">
      <span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-question-circle">?</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: That's exactly right ! Removing my answer which is the same

Comment: @Manuel Sorry - Is there a way to do this only by messing with style of "cssthis"? I think the answer might be no.

Comment: @BGS totally depends what existing styles are already present on everything else.

Answer (score 0):

```
.field-group{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox for this:

```css
.field-group {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px; 
  align-items: center;
}

.field-group > * {
  display: block;
}

.field-group label {
  margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

```html
<form class="aui">
    <div class="field-group">
      
      <label for="comment-input">Comment</label>

      <textarea class="textarea" ></textarea>
      <a id="cssthis" href="#" fieldhelp="" data-helplink="local" style="">x
        <span class="aui-icon aui-icon-small aui-iconfont-question-circle"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Instead of using `margin-top:-30px` for .field-group label  , you should use `  margin-bottom: auto;`  and it will stick label to top dynamically.

Comment: @OptimumCreative Thank you very much. I was also thinking about how I could do it differently. Because margin-top didn't really feel like a clean solution. But margin-bottom: auto; does. Thank you! 